# Calibration of a Panoramic image

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the calibration files (yaml) for a panoramic image. The image has been already rectified (unwrapped) using other the Taylor expansion method (OcamCalib Toolbox in MATLAB), but I'm not sure if in order to process it further I need to obtain the calibration parameters given by *camera_calibration*.

In other words, given a 360 degree Field-of-view lens, is the pinhole model used by  *camera_calibration* applicable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10809/calibration-of-a-panoramic-image/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

once you have warped your images, the calibration does not makes sense anymore.

Moreover, a 360 degree image does not fit a pinhole camera model.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2